# Dynamic TextViews OnCLickListener not triggering first time the Activity loads

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have a `LinearLayout` that gets populated with `TextViews`.  Each of those `TextViews` gets set with the same `OnClickListener`.  The Listener DOES get triggered, but only on the SECOND time the Activity loads.

How can I get it to trigger the first time through / why is it not triggering the first time?

```
public static void loadArticlesIntoSimilarList(Context mContext, String myid)
{
    //POPULATES THE LIST OF ARTICLES
    //associatedArticles = articlesDataSource.getAssociatedArticlesData(articleId);
    for(final Article similarArticle : articlesDataSource.getAssociatedArticlesList(myid))
    {
        TextView similarArticleTextView = new TextView(mContext);
        similarArticleTextView.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.meddark_gray));

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        similarArticleTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layoutParams.setMargins(ConversionHelper.dpToPx(5), 0, ConversionHelper.dpToPx(5), ConversionHelper.dpToPx(20));

        similarArticleTextView.setText(similarArticle.title);
        similarArticleTextView.setId((int) similarArticle.id);

        similarArticlesLinearLayout.addView(similarArticleTextView);
        similarArticleTextView.setClickable(true);
        similarArticleTextView.setOnClickListener(relatedArticleClickListener);
        similarArticleTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
}
```

I'm first setting the **listener** at the top:

```
private static OnClickListener relatedArticleClickListener;
```

And the **function** is:

```
    //RELATED ARTICLE CLICK
    relatedArticleClickListener = new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("MYLOG", "RL Article clicked " + v.getId());
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),MainActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("id", v.getId());
            startActivity(myIntent);
            finish();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Can you post the assignment of relatedArticleListener? Where is this for loop located in your Activity?  Where is the assignment being done? What leads you to believe it is not getting triggered the first time?

Comment: Do you initialized the `relatedArticleClickListener` where you defined it(as a field in the class)? If not, you may be initializing the `TextViews` with a `null `OnCLickListener`(`relatedArticleClickListener` not being initialized at that moment) and then assigning a value to the `relatedArticleClickListener`. Because you declare `relatedArticleClickListener` as `static` it would make sense that next time you set the `OnClickListener`, the `TextViews` will react as the reference will be valid.

Comment: @Luksprog - I'm not sure I follow, but - is there a suggestion on how to overcome this hidden in there or just an explanation of what might be going wrong?  If so, I will read through more thoroughly (sorry I'm a noob!)  Thanks for any/all advice!

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://gist.github.com/4508749 I'm just assuming some things as I don't know your full code.

Comment: Luksprog: that might be it, but it's so late my brain isn't awake enough to verify - seems a good start and I will look in the morning. Thank you very much for your help this far.